# Cache all records from query in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm trying to cache all records of the query for 60 minutes by the following method (Method 1)

```php
Route::get('categoryList', function() {
   return app\CategoryDetails::remember(60)->get();
});
```

I followed this tutorial [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/25-laravel-tips-and-tricks--pre-92818) (Tip 5: Cache Database Queries)

But I'm getting this error:

> Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()`

I don't know what I'm missing here.

BTW, I know I can cache entire records by the following method (Method 2):

```php
Route::get('categoryList', function() {    
    $category = Cache::remember('category', 10, function() {
        return \App\CategoryDetails::all();
    });

    return $category;
});
```

and this is working perfectly.

I am just curious why the first method is not working for me.

Comment: The first method was used in Laravel 4, the latter is used in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Laravel 5 removed this functionality. You now have to [store the cache yourself](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#cache-usage):

```php
Route::get('categoryList', function () {
    return Cache::remember('category-details', 60, function () {
        return App\CategoryDetails::all();
    });
});
```

From [the upgrade docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0):

> Eloquent no longer provides the `remember` method for caching queries. You now are responsible for caching your queries manually using the `Cache::remember` function.

Comment: Is any where they documented this one ? just curious to know.

Comment: @MuhammedKhalander - Yes. I added it to my answer.

Comment: :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :*

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a laravel eloquent query caching library called [rememberable](https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable)

It does a pretty good job.